# Slick: How can I combine a SQL LIKE statement with a SQL IN statement

Tags: scala, slick, sql-like, sql-in

I basically would like to replace the following code with something more "slicky":

```
final case class User(firstName: String, lastName: String)

def dbAction(lastNameParts: Seq[String]): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[User], User, Effect]
implicit val getUserResult =
  GetResult((r: PositionedResult) => {
    val resultSet: ResultSet = r.rs
    User(
      resultSet.getString(1),
      resultSet.getString(2)
    )
  })
val pattern = orgIds.mkString("|")
sql"""SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name
      FROM users u
      WHERE last_name ~* $pattern""".as[User]
```

So the resulting SQL would be:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM users u
WHERE last_name ~* '%bar|baz%';
```

So this dbAction will return an action which I can use to Query for all users having some name parts included in a list.

So

```
dbAction(Seq("bar", "baz"))
```

will return an action querying for all last names containing the strings "bar" or "baz" (case insensitive). 
I found a way to query for a single pattern

```
val query = for {
  user <- users if user.lastName like "%bar%"
} yield (user.firstName, user.lastName)
```

and I found a way to query for list inclusion

```
u <- users if u.lastName.inSet(Seq("bar", "baz"))
```

but could not find a way to combine that

EDIT: Another way to possibly solve that would be via a regular expression. Is there a way to achieve something like the following SQL statement:

```
select * from users where last_name ~ '[\w]*bar[\w]*|[\w]*baz[\w]*';
```

Since this is somehow a different question how to use a regex I created a different question for this:
[Slick: Is there a way to create a WHERE clause with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218122/slick-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-where-clause-with-a-regex)

Comment: `if (user.lastName like "%bar%") && user.lastName.inSet(Seq("bar", "baz"))` will not work? Would be interesting to look at generated SQL statement

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve. I want to achieve the same result as with the sql statement above in the first code section. I will add the interpolated sql statement in an edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code you've posted, I didn't think you needed to literaly combine an `IN` with a `LIKE`. I read the question as wanting to do a regular expression query. Although Slick doesn't support the `~*` operator out of the box, you can add it yourself. That would give you a way to execute the query using the *lifted embedded* style of Slick query.

To do that, you can use the `SimpleExpression` builder. There's not much documentation on it, but the jumping off point would be the [Scalar Database Functions](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/userdefined.html#scalar-database-functions) page of the reference manual.

What we want to do is write a method along these lines:

```
def find(names: Seq[String]): DBIO[Seq[String]] = {
  val pattern = names.mkString("|")
  users.filter(_.lastName regexLike pattern).map(_.lastName).result
}
```

To get `regexLike` we can enrich (enhance, "pimp") a string column to have the `regexLike` method:

```
implicit class RegexLikeOps(s: Rep[String]) {
  def regexLike(p: Rep[String]): Rep[Boolean] = {
    val expr = SimpleExpression.binary[String,String,Boolean] { (s, p, qb) =>
      qb.expr(s)
      qb.sqlBuilder += " ~* "
      qb.expr(p)
    }
    expr.apply(s,p)
  }
}
```

The `implicit class` part is allow the compiler to construct the `RegexLikeOps` class anytime it has a `Rep[String]` that calls a method that `Rep[String]` doesn't already have (i.e., when `regexLike` is asked for).

Our `regexLike` method takes another `Rep[String]` argument as the pattern, and then uses `SimpleExpression` builder to safely construct the SQL we want to use.

Putting it all together we can write:

```
val program = for {
  _ <- users.schema.create
  _ <- users ++= User("foo") :: User("baz") :: User("bar") :: Nil
  result <- find( Seq("baz","bar") )
} yield result

println( Await.result(db.run(program), 2.seconds) )
```

The SQL generated (in my test with H2) is:

```
select "last_name" from "app_user" where "last_name" ~* 'baz|bar'
```

The full code is: https://github.com/d6y/so46199828

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you. If I see this right you could basically create any kind of sql operator right? Cool feature.

Comment: @Stoecki Yup, it's a useful feature. Sort of related, and in case you've not seen it, there's also https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg which adds other features for Postgres.

Comment: @RichardDallaway Yes, I found this repository today, but didn't look deeper into it so far. But I will. Thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine these 2 query conditions:

```
import slick.lifted.Tag
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

object Test {
  final case class User(firstName:String, lastName:String, id:Long = 0l)

  class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user"){
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
    def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
    def * = (firstName, lastName, id).mapTo[User]
  }



  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2config")
    val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

    val initialData = Seq(
      User("Alex", "Arendar"),
      User("David", "Arora"),
      User("Dude", "Stoecki"),
      User("Alexander", "the Great")
    )

    Await.result(
      db.run(
        users.schema.create  andThen (users ++= initialData)
      ), 3 seconds
    )

    val query1 = for {
      user <- users if user.firstName like "%Alex%"
    } yield (user.firstName, user.lastName)

    println(query1.result.statements.head)
    println(Await.result(db.run(query1.result), 3 seconds))

    val query2 = for {
      user <- users if (user.firstName like "%Alex%") && user.firstName.inSet(Seq("Alex", "David"))
    } yield (user.firstName, user.lastName)

    println(query2.result.statements.head)
    println(Await.result(db.run(query2.result), 3 seconds))

    db.close()
  }
```

My console output is:

```
select "first_name", "last_name" from "user" where "first_name" like '%Alex%'
Vector((Alex,Arendar), (Alexander,the Great))
select "first_name", "last_name" from "user" where ("first_name" like '%Alex%') and ("first_name" in ('Alex', 'David'))
Vector((Alex,Arendar))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see generated SQL does contain both `like` and `in` parts.

I used in-memory H2 database here but I think this shall work with any RDBMS.

Comment: This is not what I want. I have a list of patterns like Seq("%le%", %av%) and want a query against this list of patterns, not connecting a SQL-like statement with an SQL-in statement. The result of your data example  would be Vector((Alex,Arendar), ("David", "Arora"), (Alexander,the Great)). Thank you so far.