# Slick: Is there a way to create a WHERE clause with a regex?

Tags: regex, scala, slick

I look for a slick equivalient to

```
select * from users where last_name ~* '[\w]*son';
```

So for example when having the following names in the database:

```
first_name | last_name
----------------------
Tore       | Isakson
John       | Smith
Solveig    | Larsson
Marc       | Finnigan
```

The result would be

```
first_name | last_name
----------------------
Tore       | Isakson
Solveig    | Larsson
```

My current solution is to interpolate this with an SQLActionBuilder like

```
val pattern = "[\\w]*son"
val action = sql""" SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name ~* ${pattern}; """.as[User]
```

But this is not the way I would like to have it. I would prefer something like

```
users.filter(_.last_name matchRegex "[\\w]*son")   // <- This does not exist
```

In case it is relevant: I use Postgres.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answer is following the question in [Slick: How can I combine a SQL LIKE statement with a SQL IN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199828/))

Although Slick doesn't support the `~*` operator out of the box, you can add it yourself. That would give you a way to execute the query using the *lifted embedded* style of Slick query.

To do that, you can use the `SimpleExpression` builder. There's not much documentation on it, but the jumping off point would be the [Scalar Database Functions](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/userdefined.html#scalar-database-functions) page of the reference manual.

What we want to do is write a method along these lines:

```
def find(names: Seq[String]): DBIO[Seq[String]] = {
  val pattern = names.mkString("|")
  users.filter(_.lastName regexLike pattern).map(_.lastName).result
}
```

To get `regexLike` we can use a enrich (enhance, "pimp") a string column to have the `regexLike` method:

```
implicit class RegexLikeOps(s: Rep[String]) {
  def regexLike(p: Rep[String]): Rep[Boolean] = {
    val expr = SimpleExpression.binary[String,String,Boolean] { (s, p, qb) =>
      qb.expr(s)
      qb.sqlBuilder += " ~* "
      qb.expr(p)
    }
    expr.apply(s,p)
  }
}
```

The `implicit class` part is allow the compiler to construct the `RegexLikeOps` class anytime it has a `Rep[String]` that calls a method that `Rep[String]` doesn't already have (i.e., when `regexLike` is asked for).

Our `regexLike` method takes another `Rep[String]` argument as the pattern, and then uses `SimpleExpression` builder to safely construct the SQL we want to use.

Putting it all together we can write:

```
val program = for {
  _ <- users.schema.create
  _ <- users ++= User("foo") :: User("baz") :: User("bar") :: Nil
  result <- find( Seq("baz","bar") )
} yield result

println( Await.result(db.run(program), 2.seconds) )
```

The SQL generated (in my test with H2) is:

```
select "last_name" from "app_user" where "last_name" ~* 'baz|bar'
```

The full code is: https://github.com/d6y/so46199828